# html form input inside iframe not showing virtual keyboard when focus

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe, keyboard

so i just find out every input field that is inside iframe (in my case: stripe's cc number, expiry date, and cvc input fields) doesn't show virtual keyboard when it's focused. how to replicate this isssue in desktop is by using chrome extension virtual keyboard. in my case, it's in occulus VR device.

https://www.screencast.com/t/DpzY9WkKOkB

how can i force the keyboard to show when the input inside iframe is focus using JS ?